# Count sum of non-empty cells in a column when corresponding row in an adjacent column holds specific value - VBA or formula?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, countif

Currently, I have a range (`A1:M22`) where for each column (`A` through `M`) I count the number of non-empty cells at row 23.

I am using the `COUNTBLANK` function. However, not all rows are to be included in the total count at row 23 in each column.

Thus, I have added column `N`, where for each row I have indicated whether the specific row should be included in the count or not. The sheet looks like this:

[image: Image of table]

As indicated in column `N`, Person 4, Person 7 and Person 15 are not to be counted in the total of employees with a salary even though they appear in the overview. This is due to the fact that perform a task that isn't relevant for the total baseline.

Taking the month of February for an example, the count should be 10 instead of 12, since Person 4 and Person 7 had a salary that month but shouldn't be included in the total.

My question is then, how do I account for this when calculating the count of employees with a salary for each month? Is it possible to do by an elaborate formula or is VBA the better choice?

Answer (score 2):

It just looks like countifs:

```
=COUNTIFS(C3:C22,"<>",N3:N22,"Yes")
```

e.g. for February

[image]

To pull the formulas across, you would need to anchor column N:

```
=COUNTIFS(C3:C22,"<>",$N3:$N22,"Yes")
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. Hm, weird I didn't figure that out myself. Thanks alot!